# how to load excel data in already created hive table in orc format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, spark-excel

I need to load data in already created hive table in orc format.

ie I need to read data from excel sheet, create data frame and then load it into hive tables in orc format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to construct Dataframe from a Excel (xls,xlsx) file in Scala Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196741/how-to-construct-dataframe-from-a-excel-xls-xlsx-file-in-scala-spark)

Comment: I have a already created table and the data is in orc format.
now i have new excel sheet from which I have to update some values of already created hive table.
Please suggest

Comment: Okay, fine. Why can't you use the library mentioned there? SparkSQL can run any Hive statement

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps involved:

- read the excel file[1]
- write it into the Hive table [2]

The answers related to this:

1. [Reading Excel file with Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811192/reading-excel-file-with-scala)
2. [How to save DataFrame directly to Hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664008/how-to-save-dataframe-directly-to-hive)